# using Rails I18n in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have a class that generates PDF with Prawn:

```
class CustomersReport < Prawn::Document
  def to_pdf
    text "Hello, world"
    render
  end
end
```

How to use Rails I18n in this class? If I try to use `translation()` function, it prints `undefined method`translation' for CustomersReport:Class`

I tried to add `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper`to my class, but no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `I18n.t(...)` or `I18n.translate(...)`.